# Why do I get errors when i use "public void main()"

Tags: java, methods, program-entry-point

Okay so basically I was given classwork by the instructor and I'm having trouble doing anything with it. The code I received at first didn't run at all, it said it failed to find the main class. So I decided to add in `public void main(String[] args) {` and when I did most of my methods just turned red and the code has like 20 errors now even tho it didn't have any before (although the code is incomplete it shouldn't have any errors at this point).

I'm not sure whats wrong with it and I need to be able to run the code to make sure the things I need to add in later on work as intended. even though its class work it gets assessed so if anyone knows why I get tons of errors after correctly adding in a main constructor (I believe that's what they were called).

```
 public class Book {
    public String bookID;
    public String title;
    public String author;
    public String borrowerID;

    public void main(String[] args) {


    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getBookID() {
        return bookID;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public String getBorrowerID() {
        return borrowerID;
    }

    public boolean returnBook() {
        // if borrower ID has been set (ie. book has been borrowed)
        if (this.borrowerID != null) {
            // reset borrowerID to null and return true result
            this.borrowerID = null;
            return true;
        } else {
            // otherwise book is not currently borrowed so return false result
            return false;
        }
    }



    // format Book details to a String (useful for printing!)
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Book ID: %s\nTitle: %s\nAuthor: %s\nBorrowed by: %s\n", this.bookID, this.title,
                this.author, this.borrowerID != null ? this.borrowerID : "Available");
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to put your methods outside of the `main()`

Comment: The closing `}` of your `main` method is missing, and you have a superfluous one after the `toString` method . Also you are missing a `static`  keyword, the main method should be `public static void main(String[] args)` .

Answer (score 1):

Issues in your code:

- the static keyword is missing in main
- Created methods inside the main method
- no logic written when main executes
- If you want to call returnBook method inside main, you should declare static
- If you move remaining code other than main method to some other class, then you can create instance and invoke the method.

Fixed above issues in below class.

```
public class Book {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean result = returnBook();
    System.out.println(result);
}

public String bookID;
public String title;
public String author;
public static String borrowerID;

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public String getBookID() {
    return bookID;
}

public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

public String getBorrowerID() {
    return borrowerID;
}

public static boolean returnBook() {
    // if borrower ID has been set (ie. book has been borrowed)
    if (borrowerID != null) {
        // reset borrowerID to null and return true result
        borrowerID = null;
        return true;
    } else {
        // otherwise book is not currently borrowed so return false result
        return false;
    }
}

// format Book details to a String (useful for printing!)
public String toString() {
    return String.format("Book ID: %s\nTitle: %s\nAuthor: %s\nBorrowed by: %s\n", this.bookID, this.title,
                         this.author, this.borrowerID != null ? this.borrowerID : "Available");
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Just as a general rule of thumb for these single class programs - they're generally formatted as follows

```
<Start classname> 
     <Start main methodname>
           <action code>
           <access external methods here>
     </End main method>

     <Start method 1>
           <action code>
     </End method 1>

     <Start method 2>
          <action code>
     <End method 2>
     etc....
<Close class>
```

Edit: I feel like I should also mention in this case that methods can call other external methods from within their action code. This includes methods in other classes, assuming you've imported the correct package/class. For example:

```
<start method 1>
    method2();
</end method 1>

<start method 2>
   <action code>  
</end method 2>
```

in this case, calling method 1 will invoke the action code of method 2. There's another can of worms here, but that should be good to get you started.